# Confusion in Docker Command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker , can anyone please explain what does this commands do .
  As per my knowledge , I think .

```
  1st command - create a directory as the name build
  2nd command skip the test cases .
  3rd command - No Idea



  1) RUN mkdir -p /build
  2) RUN mvn -o package -DskipTests
  3) RUN ls -l target
```

what is -p ,-o,-D,-l command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets go through the command one by one

As stated by @Mihai,

> RUN is a command in the Dockerfile. Whatever comes next is the command
>   to run on the OS of the base image

1. RUN `mkdir -p /build`

   - It creates a `build` directory
   - The `-p` option: `no error if existing, make parent directories as needed`, So it will not throw an error if the directory exists.
2. RUN `mvn -o package -DskipTests`

   - It runs the `package` phase of maven
   - The `-o` option: `Work offline`
     When running with the offline option enabled, Maven will not attempt to connect to a remote repository to retrieve artifacts.
3. RUN `ls -l target`

   - ls - list directory contents of `target`directory
   - The `-l` option: use a long listing format`
     When running with the offline option enabled, Maven will not attempt to connect to a remote repository to retrieve artifacts.

> So to answer your question, **what is -p ,-o,-D,-l command**
>
> They are not commands, but options to `ls`, `mkdir` and `mvn` commands

For any information on linux commands, just search using `man any-command`

For `ls`, just do `man ls`

Answer (score 2):

The third command is only a check that the developer needed for debug. You can safely delete the line. It is there to print the contents of ./target during build time.

The flags (-p, -l, etc.) are the flags of the linux commands and you should check that in the OS. In your case, mkdir create parents as needed (doesn't really make sense in your case), ls prints a list (-l), etc.

`RUN` is a command in the Dockerfile. Whatever comes next is the command to run on the OS of the base image.

Comment: how does this command work-----> RUN ls -l target

Comment: runs 'ls -l target' inside the temporary container during image build. Just run 'docker build' and you will understand